# Elasticsearch-rails : response is empty at times, second request it returns proper response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch-rails

New to `elasticsearch-rails`. It is acting werid. 
When I call my API for the first time, at times, it responds with empty array but calling the same API again, returns proper response.

**API Output - For the first time**
[image]

**API Output- Second time**
[image]

My model :

```
class Consultation < ApplicationRecord
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  after_save :set_index
  Consultation.import force: true

  def set_index
    self.__elasticsearch__.index_document
  end
end
```

My controller :

```
 def search
      required_params_present = check_required_params(%i[search])
      if required_params_present
        searched_result = Elasticsearch::Model.search("*#{params[:search]}*", [Consultation]).records.records
        data = ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(searched_result, each_serializer: ConsultationSerializer)
        send_response(HTTP_STATUS_CODE_200, true, I18n.t('search'), data)
      else
        send_response(HTTP_STATUS_CODE_801, false, I18n.t('params_missing.error'))
      end
 rescue => e
      send_response(HTTP_STATUS_CODE_500, false, e.message)
 end
```

Response is empty only for the first time.
Is it that Elasticsearch take times to respond for the first time?

Any help or ideas will be really appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Newly indexed documents are not yet searchable immediately (within ~1 second), for performance reasons. See [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html)

You'll need to do a manual "refresh" on the index, if you want realtime search result. However, I quote below

> While a refresh is much lighter than a commit, it still has a performance cost. A manual refresh can be useful when writing tests, but don’t do a manual refresh every time you index a document in production; it will hurt your performance. Instead, your application needs to be aware of the near real-time nature of Elasticsearch and make allowances for it.

In **test** environment, this is perfectly acceptable to do a "refresh" just so you could test immediately that the documents are already searchable.

Because it seems that you are on **development**, I would advise against this, but you may still free to do so with something like below

```
def set_index
  config = (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?) ? { refresh: true } : {}
  self.__elasticsearch__.index_document config
end
```

Comment: But I am setting index in after_save. The records were created couple of days back. So index is already set for them. This happens everytime I close server and start again.

Comment: I tried your code. No luck ! Still same problem exists :(

Comment: Hmm. I'm not too sure what the problem is anymore.